# Can't cast an Item to Path in paperjs

Tags: typescript, paperjs

Say you have:

```
let path = new Path([new pt(1, 1), new pt(2, -5)]);
path.strokeColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
```

Then you clone your path:

```
path = path.clone();
```

You get:

> TS2740: Type 'Item' is missing the following properties from type 'Path'...

Ok fine. So then you do:

```
path = path.clone() as Path;
```

And you get:

> TS2749: 'Path' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Strange... So if I go to the definition of `Path`:

```
Path: typeof Path
```

and, surprisingly the definition of `paper.Path`:

```
class Path extends PathItem {...}
```

What is going on here? Why does paperjs have such a convoluted type graph? I'm worried that doing `as paper.Path` will cause side effects on the `PaperScope` associated with `paper`.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug which I just reported [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1795) (I am the one working on Paper.js TypeScript definition generation). `path.clone()` return type should be `Path` and not `Item`.

The reason why Paper.js typescript definition is so complex is because the library has a quite old JavaScript code base, and some of its parts hard to map in TypeScript.
On top of that, the TypeScript definition is automatically generated from the code JSDoc comments which adds another level of complexity...

Anyway, I will have a look at this bug and for now, you can safely workaround the issue with a type assertion:

```
path = path.clone() as paper.Path;
```

Comment: Thanks for this - was trying to call getIntersections for ever on an Item type and typescript wouldn't stop harassing me with red underlines.